# onPress not working when make Custom Widget in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, click

i have some issue don't know what happanning when make custom widget class and pass onpress function its not working.

RoundButton dart file

```
class RoundedButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final Function press;
  final Color color, textColor;

  const RoundedButton({
    Key? key,
    required this.text,
    required this.press,
    this.color = primaryColor,
    this.textColor = Colors.white,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8),
      width: size.width * 0.8,
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
        child: TextButton(
          onPressed: press(),
          child: Text(text),
          style: TextButton.styleFrom(
              backgroundColor: color,
              primary: textColor,
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16, horizontal: 40)),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Where I call that widget.

```
RoundedButton(
          text: "LOGIN",
          press: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) {
                  return LoginScreen();
                },
              ),
            );
          },
        )
```

I tried  like  but not working

```
onPressed: press()

onPressed: (){press;}

onPressed: () =>press
```

But when I add the Navigation function directly at the RoundButton widget.

```
press: () {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) {
              return LoginScreen();
            },
          ),
        )
```

It worked.

But don't know why custom function not working.

Comment: `onPressed: press,`

Comment: flutter 2.2 onPressed: press creating error.

Comment: The argument type 'Function' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()?'.

Comment: tried brother ;(

Comment: `final VoidCallback press;` will work and then `onPressed: press,`

Comment: but can u plz explain what is different btw Function and VoidCallback @moneeralhashim

Comment: `VoidCallback` is an alias for `void Function()` `TextButton` is expecting type `VoidCallback?` which means you can also pass `null` The `Function`  type you had earlier didn't work because it allowed arguments to be passed. Which is the difference between `Function` and `Function()` It also was not nullable. So basically you were passing the wrong type

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `final Function press;` to `final VoidCallback press;` in your RoundedButton class and keep the rest of the code as is. Worked fine for me :)

Answer (score 0):

the only we need to do is add .call() to the end of the function to be void.
onPressed: ()=>onPressed   to onPressed: ()=>onPressed.call()

Answer (score 0):

make your press variable

from this

```
final Funcction press;
```

to this

```
final VoidCallback press;
```

then down in your widget build remove the press braces to be like this

```
onPressed: press,
```

this should work

Answer (score -1):

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8),
      width: size.width * 0.8,
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
        child: TextButton(
          onPressed: press(),   // call just press ,here u r calling the func // right after the widget is rendered. Its worked fine for me in versions b4 //null safety.
```

```
 child: Text(text),
          style: TextButton.styleFrom(
              backgroundColor: color,
              primary: textColor,
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16, horizontal: 40)),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```